# C++ auto type deduction when declaring variables without initialisation

Tags: c++, auto, type-deduction

I actually really like the automatic type deduction in C++, where I can have an arbitrarily complex return type from a function, but not worry about what the type is when calling the function.

In other words, something like:

```
std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::string>> getCollection() { ... }
auto myMapArray = getCollection();
```

However, this appears to work only if the compiler *can* deduce the type, such as when it's initialised from the function.

I often find myself in a situation where I just want a default-constructed variable of the correct type (usually a class member variable) and it pains me to have to do:

```
std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::string>> getCollection();
std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::string>> m_collection;
```

in this case. But I know of no other way to avoid the long type names, other than using `typedef` or the more modern `using`:

```
typedef std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::string>> VecOfMaps;
using VecOfMaps = std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::string>>;
:
VecOfMaps m_collection;
```

It appears it would be useful to allow type deduction of a variable as if it were something returned from a function, such as with:

```
std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::string>> getCollection() { ... }
auto m_collection = asif(getCollection);
```

You wouldn't need to provide parameters since all overloads are required to return the same type. So my questions are really:

- Is there a better way than type aliasing to do this?
- Are the any obvious shortcomings to the `asif` solution (it would have to allow for templated functions but that should just be a minor extension)?

Comment: You pointed out why it is impossible in general: *"all overloads are required to return the same type"*. You have to encode that information somehow.

Comment: @Passer, yes, it does, but it's *already* encoded in the function, I'm not sure why we would need to encode it again for a variable that is expected to be set by *calling* that function.

Comment: The best answer I believe is because the language is designed so. The limit to which compilers deduce your intent is locally. Imagine this being in a class template, you could have functions being found arbitrarily far after the member definition.

Comment: Would it help to consider `decltype()`? [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6909b9d4aea036eb)

Comment: Given your rep I would say this question is purely opinion-based. My opinion: *vector-of-maps-of-strings* carries insufficient knowledge about its purpose, and thus reduces code redability. It should always be typedef'd to a more descriptive custom type.

Comment: @rustyx, one can have a high rep but not necessarily in a specific domain.

Comment: @Scheff, if you want to make that an answer, I suspect it's what I was after. Can I do a `decltype(fn()) variable;` *without* a type alias, or do I need to actually create a type alias: `using FnType = decltype(fn()); FnType variable;`? It looks like I can do the former but I want to make sure it's a standard thing and not just a gcc extension. But, in any case, it's better as an answer so I can accept it and have it searchable for future people.

Comment: `decltype` is a standard facility since C++11 and can be used in (almost?) all places where type-specifiers are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your comment:

> It appears it would be useful to allow type deduction of a variable as if it were something returned from a function, such as with:
>
> ```
> std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::string>> getCollection() { ... }
> auto m_collection = asif(getCollection);
> ```

It appears to me that `asif()` sounds somehow like [**decltype()**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype).

In this case, it is the return type of function which is required, hence it should be

```
decltype(getCollection()) m_collection;
```

I must admit that I'm not that experienced with the practical use of `decltype()` in daily business and fiddled myself a bit (out of curiosity), ending up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

auto func() { return std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::string>>(); }

struct Class {
  typedef decltype(func()) VarType;
  VarType var;
};

int main()
{
  Class obj;
  std::cout << "type of Class::var: " << typeid(obj.var).name() << '\n';
}
```

The output of that is:

> `type of Class::var: St6vectorISt3mapINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES6_St4lessIS6_ESaISt4pairIKS6_S6_EEESaISD_EE`

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6909b9d4aea036eb)

So far, so good.

---

> Can I do a `decltype(fn()) variable;` without a type alias?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

auto func() { return std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::string>>(); }

struct Class {
  decltype(func()) var;
};

int main()
{
  Class obj;
  std::cout << "type of Class::var: " << typeid(obj.var).name() << '\n';
}
```

Output:

> `type of Class::var: St6vectorISt3mapINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES6_St4lessIS6_ESaISt4pairIKS6_S6_EEESaISD_EE`

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1bad1615279a8a6)

I must admit that it was one of the samples in the linked [decltype()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) documentation which made me sure about this.

Furthermore, I would like to mention that `decltype()` is (similar like e.g. `sizeof`) a compile-time type-only evaluation. Hence, it even works if there is no implementation of `func()` available at all:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::string>> func();

struct Class {
  decltype(func()) var;
};

int main()
{
  Class obj;
  std::cout << "type of Class::var: " << typeid(obj.var).name() << '\n';
}
```

Output:

> `type of Class::var: St6vectorISt3mapINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES6_St4lessIS6_ESaISt4pairIKS6_S6_EEESaISD_EE`

[**Live Demo at coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e75d998fa12eae5d)

---

> It looks like I can do the former but I want to make sure it's a standard thing and not just a gcc extension.

As far as I know, `decltype()` is in fact a C++ standard feature (since C++11 and the fact that it is mentioned in `cppreference.com` would count as "proof" to me).

Aside from this, I used the last sample to check it with

- clang 10.0.0 `-std=c++11`
- gcc 10.1 `-std=c++11`
- msvc v19.24 `/std:c++14` (`/std:c++11` is not an available option.)

All passed this check on [**CompilerExplorer**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/N_VyPn).